# Not able to display the time format data from the firebase database connected to my Angular app

Tags: angularjs, html, firebase, angularfire

Am trying to display the time format data from the firebase database, that I have connected to the angular app, the html tag with the input type"text"  is displaying fine on the dashboard but there is the problem with the time format and it is not getting displayed.

**Here is the below HTML code**

```
<div class = "row" ng-controller = "taskCtrl" >
<div class = "col-md-5">

<h3> Add Task </h3>

<form ng-submit= "addtask()">
<div class="form-group">
       <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="X as X.Appname for X in appy">
</select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label >Task Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "tname" placeholder="Task Name">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label >Task Description</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "tdes" placeholder="Task Description">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label >Task start time </label>
    <input type= "text" class="form-control" ng-model = "tstime" placeholder="Task start time" >
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label >Task Info</label>
    <input type="time" class="form-control" ng-model = "tetime" placeholder="Task end time">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label >Phone number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "phno" placeholder="Phone number">
  </div>  

<button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
    </div>
<div class = "col-md-7">
    <h3> Contacts</h3>
    <table class= "table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Task Name </th>
            <th>Task Description</th>
            <th>Task Start time </th>
            <th>Task End Time </th>
            <th> Task Status </th>

        </tr>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat = "tas in task">
            <td> {{tas.tname}}</td>
            <td> {{tas.tdes}}</td>
             <td> {{tas.tstime}}</td>
             <td> {{tas.tetime}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </thead>


    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the below javascript code :**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.task', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/task', {
    templateUrl: 'views/task.html',
    controller: 'taskCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('taskCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray',function($scope, $firebaseArray) {


var ref = new Firebase('https://contactlist9934.firebaseio.com/task');
$scope.task = $firebaseArray(ref);

var ref3 = new Firebase('https://contactlist9934.firebaseio.com/application');
$scope.appy = $firebaseArray(ref3);

$scope.addtask = function(){

var r1;
var r2;
var r3;
var r4;

r1 = $scope.tstime.toString();
r2  = r1.substring(16,24);
r3 = $scope.tetime.toString();
r4  = r3.substring(16,24);


    $scope.task.$add({

        tname: $scope.tname,
        tdes: $scope.tdes,
        etime: r2,
        ttime: r4,
        appname: $scope.selectedName.Appname

    }).then(function(ref){

        var id = ref.key();
        console.log('Added Task' +id);
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.email = '';


            });

          }





}])

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {



     });
```

The text fields are getting displayed fine but the time format is not getting diaplayed, help me out on this one !!

Comment: Can you provide an example what does the variable `tstime` look like?

Comment: This question should be closed since it was just a typo as stated in the comment on an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed now, as I was trying to fetch the data from the firebase, the below variables should match in the below codes :- -

HTML

```
 <tr ng-repeat = "tas in taski">
            <td> {{tas.tname}}</td>
            <td> {{tas.tdes}} </td>
             <td> {{tas.etime}}</td>
             <td> {{tas.ttime}}</td>
             <td> {{tas.appname}}</td>

        </tr>
```

Script

```
$scope.task.$add({

        tname: $scope.tname,
        tdes: $scope.tdes,
        etime: $scope.tstime,
        ttime: r4,
        appname: $scope.selectedName.Appname

    }).then(function(ref)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter for this and convert the `tstime` and `tetime` in your controller to your desired format like this:

```
$scope.tstime = $filter('date')($scope.tstime, 'yyyy/MM/dd'); 
$scope.tetime = $filter('date')($scope.tetime, 'yyyy/MM/dd');
```

Or if you want to use a directive and use it in multiple inputs you can make a directive something like this:

```
.directive('formatDate', ['$timeout', '$filter', function ($timeout, $filter) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
      var dateFormat = 'yyyy/MM/dd';
      $ctrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
        var pDate = Date.parse(viewValue);
        if (isNaN(pDate) === false) {
          return new Date(pDate);
        }
        return undefined;
      });
      $ctrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
        var pDate = Date.parse(modelValue);
        if (isNaN(pDate) === false) {
          return $filter('date')(new Date(pDate), dateFormat);
        }
        return undefined;
      });
      $element.on('blur', function () {
        var pDate = Date.parse($ctrl.$modelValue);
        if (isNaN(pDate) === true) {
          $ctrl.$setViewValue(null);
          $ctrl.$render();
        } else {
          if ($element.val() !== $filter('date')(new Date(pDate), dateFormat)) {
            $ctrl.$setViewValue($filter('date')(new Date(pDate), dateFormat));
            $ctrl.$render();
          }
        }

      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

And bind it to your input like this:

```
<input type= "text" class="form-control" format-date ng-model="tstime" placeholder="Task start time">
<input type="time" class="form-control" format-date ng-model="tetime" placeholder="Task end time">
```

Comment: Will this filter work for the time ? i preferably assume that you are taking this filter for the date ? am extracting the time field from the format and pushing only the time field into the database by converting this to the string.

Comment: I asked you in a comment to provide a example of what the `tstime`/`tetime` is like. Can you tell me that and I can help you further? :)

Comment: Thepio thanks for the input, i had given the wrong name, for the tstime/tetime this was present in the database as the tetime/ttime when i changed it started working...Thank you really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Ok, good to hear that you got it working! And no problem, I try my best :P